# Is a registered custom executable format also described by an object of type `linux_binfmt`?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, executable-format

*Understanding the Linux Kernel* says

> An executable format is described by an object of type `linux_binfmt`,
>   which essentially provides three methods: `load_binary`, `load_shlib`,
>   and `core_dump`.

and

> Linux allows users to register their own custom executable formats. 
>   To register a new format, the user writes into the register file of
>   the binfmt_misc special filesystem (usually mounted on
>   `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc`) a string with the following format:
>
> ```
> :name:type:offset:string:mask:interpreter:flags
> ```
>
> When the kernel determines that the executable file has a custom
>   format, it starts the proper interpreter program. The interpreter
>   program runs in User Mode, receives as its parameter the pathname of
>   the executable file, and carries on the computation. As an example, an
>   executable file containing a Java program is dealt by a java virtual
>   machine such as `/usr/lib/java/bin/java`.

Although it doesn't mention this, is a registered custom executable format also described by an object of type `linux_binfmt`?

If yes, registering the custom executable format doesn't require us to explicitly provide `load_binary`, `load_shlib`, and `core_dump` methods. Are the three methods created implicitly from the registration?

Without  `load_binary` method, what method does the kernel call to execute executable files of a registered executable format, via the corresponding interpreter?

Comment: Kernel is not "calling the misc executable", it's only calling the registered interpreter (which is a "normal", most often elf, binary in itself). Think of it as fancy "shebang" - when you invoke the shell script, what is actually executed by the kernel is "/bin/bash" (or whatever) elf binary, not the script file itself.

Answer (score 2):

In `binfmt-misc`’s case, the `linux_binfmt` object corresponds to the `binfmt-misc` module itself. Modules don’t have to provide implementations of all the functions; `binfmt-misc` [only declares an implementation of `load_binary`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/binfmt_misc.c?id=19f391eb05b8b005f2907ddc8f284487b446abf3#n844):

```
static struct linux_binfmt misc_format = {
    .module = THIS_MODULE,
    .load_binary = load_misc_binary,
};
```

(`binfmt_script`, which implements support for shebang-based scripts, has a similar declaration.)

[`load_misc_binary`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/binfmt_misc.c?id=19f391eb05b8b005f2907ddc8f284487b446abf3#n130) deals with the specifics of all the registered executable types when the kernel invokes it. The kernel calls `load_misc_binary`, and then that function finds a matching registered executable type, if any, loads the corresponding interpreter, and sets the execution environment up as appropriate.